# Why ProgressDialog is not always turning in my android application?

Tags: android, progressdialog, freeze

I have made a image downloading thread to download image from desire web address. On that thread I have used a progress dialog , but the progress dialog is not turning after 3 or 4 second, it seems that, it is hanged. But the background work is ok. My problem is , what the progress dialog is not turning ? what it is looking like hang? 
I am using this code at the start position.

```
imageUploadhandler.postDelayed(runImageUpload, 500);
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(AllProductActivityPictGrid.this, "",
                "Message...", true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
```

Comment: accept answersto your previous questions..

Answer (score 2):

Your dialog hangs, because if you instantiated your `Handler` in an `Activity`, then everything you post to the `Handler` will run on the UI thread, not on a background Thread.

Do your downloading and create the `ProgressDialog` in an `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take a look at `AsyncTask` ?

```
 protected void onPreExecute() {
      progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(context,"Please Wait..","Retrieving data from device",false);
    }


  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    //background stuff here

    return "";
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        progressDialog.dismiss(); 
        Toast.makeText(context, "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dialog.dismiss() after you your download is completed.

Please use following code to call Progress Dialog.

```
  ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
  progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
  progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
  progressDialog.show();

  After completion of your task call  progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: I have used dialog.dismiss() after finishing the job. It is finishing after doing the job. But my problem is Progress dialog wheel is not turning after sometime.

Comment: @TKumar Please find the changes in my post try and to use that.